# DataGridViewCellStyle how to style button?

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I'm a beginner in C# and I'm trying to style a DataGridView button in Windows Forms.

I don't know how to, as example, remove the border from a button or change the hover color.
Many configurations that are on a normal button are missing in the DataGridView settings.

How can I achieve a full editable button inside DataGridView?

Answer (score 0):

Datagridview works a little different than normal buttons,
but you can still edit several things in it if you search for the subproperties inside the properties. Let's go in a bit of detail:

**DefaultCellStyle**

Once you've selected your dataGridView, go to properties > RowTemplate. In there, you find something called `DefaultCellStyle`. if you press on the '...' at the right. then it'll open a popup that allows you to change some of the standard design of the Cells.
The same can also be applied to `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`, which is almost the same as DefaultCellStyle.

**Columns**

You can also go to `Columns` and add a new Column. After you've added a new column, you're also able to set several properties unique to that Column as well. You can even set all the cells in a Column to act as buttons!
Datagridview has certainely the access to customise, but most of them are divided in the cellstyles and column collections.

**Changing the backcolor on hover**

This in't as easily done as on a normal button, I did a search and came with this solution:

In properties, at the lightning button, you can see the events, there you can doubleclick on 'CellMouseMove' and add this. (Change the `datagridview1` name eventually to be equall to yours)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Then doubleclick the 'CellMouseLeave' event so it can revert the color.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

I hope this has helped you further.

Comment: Thanks but I still cannot find way ho to change for example hover color on DataGridView Button.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to help you with specifically the hover function, but that's all I can do now.

Comment: I cannot get rid out of gray hover effect when i hover button. I am changing color by CellMouseEnter event but still getting gray.

Comment: Btw. I am using Flat style. https://imgur.com/a/rNCjN <- Example. Green is normal and gray is hovered even my function to MouseEnter red color works.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, so the MouseMove and MouseEnter events works, but the MouseLeave doesn't? weird...Can you show me what you got in the code now?

Comment: Everythong works well, but I am getting still gray button even I have red set.